# Why fabric texture is not depicted in blender?

Tags: texturing, objects

I have created a texture in Substance painter including fabrics.
[image]
I have applied it to my model in Blender and everything is ok except the fabrics.

This is how it looks in Blender:

[image]

Why it is not depicted in Blender?

Appreciate your reply.

Comment: You're missing a normal / displacement, or it's not displaying. Tell us which renderer you're using, and take a screen-grab of your shader tree?

Comment: See how to make screenshots here : https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html

Comment: hmm looks like a normal map rather than micro-displacement. Check any tut for normal maps, it will give you few hints.